# PHP Server-side timer that executes MySQL query even if user leaves website?

Tags: php, mysql, timer

I'm writing a website where users can order products, but the catch is that the products should automatically checkout (executes PHP script including MySQL queries) after 5 minutes even if the users logout/close the browser, etc. Has anyone had a problem similar to this. How should I go about coding this?

Comment: What do you mean 'automatically' checkout?

Comment: I mean it automatically runs a script which adds the appropriate information to the 'checkouts' table in my database. Also, an email should be sent to both parties (buyer and seller) of checkout information (price, quantity, product name) etc. Essentially, I need a timed PHP script to run.

Comment: To me a checkout is when you go to pay. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkout

Comment: I'm not sure if you're deliberately trying to be patronizing by posting that link or I'm just getting the impression that you are. I'm perfectly aware of what a checkout literally is. In any case, the user provides their payment info beforehand (ie credit card number) and the checkout occurs automatically because we have the payment info we need.

Comment: No I am not trying to be patronizing. Just speaking English and therefore your question was not clear. Perhaps rephrase it? Might be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a recurring automated task, you will need to set up a cron or other task scheduler. Crudely, this is how it would work:

1. When user adds product to shopping cart, it goes into database with a flag indicating that its not checked out along with timestamp of addition to db/shopping cart.
2. If the product is checkout by the user explicitly from the browser, this flag is updated to reflect the same.
3. The cron wakes up every one or two mins and checks this table for timestamps of items added to shopping cart without checkout flag updated and added more than 5 mins before.
4. It checks out such products and updates flag.

Please note that you will still need to further tweak this flow to handle situations like what happens if the user is manually checking out while your cron is doing the same etc etc

But on a nutshell I think this is how I would proceed to tackle the issue

Answer (score 1):

Store the info related to products to be checked out in database.
A cron job running every minute will cause checkout for products 5 min old.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do.  MySQL as far as I know cannot have a timed delay.  You can have a cron job that runs and executes statements.  What I would do is make an extra field in the shopping cart table and set a future checkout time.  Make a cron job that runs every minute on the server.  Have that cron job just do a quick poll of shopping carts with checkout times less than the current time.  If it finds one, run the checkout procedure on that cart and either delete it or mark it as checked-out so that it doesn't re-check it out again.

While I can't provide you with sample code as you haven't provided anything, this will at least give you a jumping off point.

Answer (score 1):

Surely a person wants a similar experience to visiting a store?

Like picking up things and wandering around.

Perhaps that person has decided to leave the basket at the counter? By all means have a product on offer for a time period and inform them that the time is up (or needs to be bought withing X minutes)

So why the auto checkout stuff?

One assumes that you do not want a bad reputation over a person deciding not to buy something and you are taking the cash? Perhaps that persons internet connection has died/laptop ran out of power/...?

Just please let them have to go through a checkout and it will paid better dividends than being automatic sold stuff they might not want....

Comment: lol I'm not taking the cash. Basically users buy products from other users, kind of like eBay. I agree with the whole making the user experience better, I am intending to add a setting to enable the user to cancel the timer if they wish to do so, and to disable the timer on any future purchases, etc.

Comment: @Hesson - Checkout is the wrong word. You mean end of that offer. See http://www.thefreedictionary.com/checkout+line http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/checkout etc

Answer (score 0):

I really think that 5 minutes is to small duration for this kind of verification, but you should have a cron job which runs a php script every 5-10 minutes which verify the last date of users activities and the last (unfinished) orders. If date is smallest then actual date `time()` minus 5 minutes, then you should delete the entries of that user from db.

The verification should be made from orders table, and not for every existing user.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is leaving the page, I suppose he requested the page (it was not automatically executed, like a cronjob).

The normal behaviour of php is to execute the script completelly, even when the usr leaves during this.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idle though - Is this shopping experience is for one off products (like antiques) or run of the mill things (like groceries)?

If the latter rather than the former, why bother? Surely a good store could replenish and therefore sell that particular product at a given price regardless. If the former an auction is required.